# Probability-There is a box. Inside we put in two balls, which can be red or blue with equal probability.

Tags: probability

There is a box. Inside we put two balls, which can be red or blue with equal probability. We take out one ball and see that it is red. We put it back. We take out another ball and see that it is red again.

What is the probability that the other ball is red?

What is the probability that both balls are red if this experiment is repeated 3 times and each time the ball we take out is red?

What is the probability that both balls are red if this experiment s repeated n times and each time the ball we take out is red?

**My attempt:**

For the first question, I did $$1/2 \cdot 1 (\text{if two balls are red})+ 1/2 \cdot 1/2 (\text{if the other ball is blue})=3/4,$$ but I guess it is wrong because teacher gave me zero points.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos  You should say or be closed.

Comment: @Emre  Please edit your question to show your attempt rather than placing it in the comments where it might be missed.  Also, you should explain your reasoning.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig is it okey now?

Comment: Yes, that is better.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 4):

Let $T_0$ be the event that the **t**otal number of reds in the box is zero.  Similarly, let $T_1$ be the event that the **t**otal number of reds in the box is one, and also define $T_2$ in the same way.

It should be clear that $\Pr(T_0)=\frac{1}{4},~\Pr(T_1)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\Pr(T_2)=\frac{1}{4}$.

Let $X_2$ be the event that if we take out two balls with replacement, both times they are red.  Similarly, define $X_n$ to be the event that if we take out $n$ balls with replacement, all $n$ times the balls are red.

It is trivial to see that $\Pr(X_n\mid T_0)=0,\Pr(X_n\mid T_1)=\frac{1}{2^n}$ and $\Pr(X_n\mid T_2)=1$

---

Your question, reworded, is asking for $\Pr(T_2\mid X_2)$ as well as $\Pr(T_2\mid X_n)$ in general.

For this, use Bayes' Theorem.  $\Pr(A\mid B) = \frac{\Pr(B\mid A)\Pr(A)}{\Pr(B)}$ and total probability $\Pr(C)=\Pr(C\mid D)\Pr(D)+\Pr(C\mid D^c)\Pr(D^c)$.

We have:

$$\Pr(T_2\mid X_2) = \dfrac{\Pr(X_2\mid T_2)\Pr(T_2)}{\Pr(X_2)}$$
$$=\dfrac{1\cdot \frac{1}{4}}{\Pr(X_2\mid T_0)\Pr(T_0)+\Pr(X_2\mid T_1)\Pr(T_1)+\Pr(X_2\mid T_2)\Pr(T_2)}$$
$$=\dfrac{1\cdot \frac{1}{4}}{0+\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{2}+1\cdot\frac{1}{4}} = \dfrac{2}{3}$$

You can similarly find $\Pr(T_2\mid X_n)$

Comment: Respected Mr. Moravitz, please, can you answer to the questions "What is the probability of putting two black balls from first box into the third if one black ball is chosen from third box? if two black balls are chosen from third box?" at this link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1149958/find-probability-that-the-choosen-ball-is-white? I will check my results.

Comment: Hey Mr. Moravitz, i couldn`t understand this part. How did we find these values. Thank you for your time. '' Pr(∣0)=0,Pr(∣1)=1/(2^n)
 and Pr(∣2)=1''

Comment: @Emre These are each able to be seen with binomial distribution if you cared to phrase it that way... but more simply with zero red balls it is impossible to draw $n$ red balls in a row.  With only red balls, it is guaranteed to draw $n$ red balls in a row... and with half red balls, we draw $n$ red balls in a row with the same probability as winning a 50-50 coin toss $n$ times in a row... namely $\frac{1}{2^n}$

Comment: @JMoravitz today in the exam, i did the bayes theorem question because of your help. Thank you again.